# Creating a queue of animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, animation, queue

I make that animate human. So I have method for `headAnimation`, `eyeAnimation`, `earAnimation`, `bodyAnimation`.

I have method `myAnimation` when i call all my animation's.

In that method I need to call animation with some delay. How can I make this without using `NSTimer` and `performSelector`.

Animation can be parallel or in series. So how can I make queue of animation or block, where I can send delay and what method call?

## Edit

I used `[self performSelector:@selector(eyeAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay: 2.0]`. And for every method animation `performSelector`.

In all animation, for example `eye`:

I use `[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
     delay:delay options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations: completion:];`.

So now in my `-(void)myAnimation` 10 `performSelector` with different delays.

So the question how I can performance this.

## Edit #2

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 delay:2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    [self eyeAnimation];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (finished) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 delay:8 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        [self earAnimation];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {


    }];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 delay:17 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        [self bodyAnimation];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {


    }];
    }
}];
```

But it difference animation then when i call `performSelector`. They aren't parallel.

Comment: How are you doing the animations in the first place? Have would the animation know if it's parallel or serial? Is that up to the queue? Have you tried anything and why didn't that work for you?

Comment: The question about "running animations one after another", "queue animations", "serial animations", "chaining multiple animations" [have been asked many times before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcore-animation%5D+queue). Did you try any of these solutions (preferably more than one) and why does none of these work for you?

Comment: So *why* didn't those solutions work? Why is your problem different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand how you combine those 2 methods above, since you're using `[UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:delay options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations: completion:];` I don't know why `[self performSelector:@selector(eyeAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay: 2.0]` is used.

Anyhow for an app I did with in a similar context as yours I did all with methods that used

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:];
```

With a block for the animations needed & in the completition block I had the logic for what needs to be done next, that's where I chained the animations & put them in correct order with duration & delay.

This works great, but if you have around 10 animations as you said. If that number is planned to increase it's better to switch on some game-engine for more complex animations, because you'd get lost with syncing all the animations.

**EDIT**

As the code you wrote in the second edit all the animations will have 0 duration. The first animation would happen after 2 seconds & after that the 2nd & 3rd animation will be called in parallel but with their delays, i.e. the 2nd animation will happen after 10 seconds & the 3rd animation will happen after 19 seconds.

What did you expected?

Comment: Because `[UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:delay options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations: completion:];` it's in `eyeAnimation` method and `perform` i use for calling this animation. If i need to call it twice i use 2 perform... So you advice to use `[UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 delay:2 * frameTime options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self eyeAnimation];}];`

Comment: Indeed, that method has all needed to control a queue of animations .. I only don't understand why you multiply the frame time by 2?

Comment: I have variable frameTime = 0.1. I don't want to write 0.2. So i write 2*frameTime. For next animation it will be 10*frameTime for example. I tried to use animateWithDuration i edit my question, but it don't make it correct. With performSelector it was nice